# Достаточно ли такой обертки над realloc в случае падения?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, realloc

В методе переопределяется строка, т.е. если она была изменена, то `realloc` память под новую строку, и копирование данных с помощью `memcpy`.

Достаточно ли такой мини обертки над `realloc` в том случае если он вернет `nullptr`?

```
bool set_object_name(const char* obj_name)
{
    if (obj_name != nullptr && strlen(obj_name) > 0)
    {
        size_t str_size = (strlen(obj_name) + 1) * sizeof(char);
        void* rresult = realloc(m_object_name, str_size);
        if (rresult == nullptr)
        {
            char* old_tmp_ptr = m_object_name;
            char* new_tmp_ptr = static_cast<char*>(malloc(str_size));

            if (new_tmp_ptr == nullptr)
            {
                m_object_name = old_tmp_ptr;
                return false;
            }
            m_object_name = new_tmp_ptr;
            free(old_tmp_ptr);
        }
        else
        {
            m_object_name = static_cast<char*>(rresult);
        }
        void* mcresult = memcpy(m_object_name, obj_name, str_size);
        if (mcresult == nullptr)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли проверку указателя, возвращаемого `malloc()` в шестой строке. Или падение на `memcpy()` при настолько жёсткой нехватке места в куче, что даже освобождение предыдущего буфера не помогает, было запланировано?

Comment: @Arhad: Запланировано, но не реализовано, точно, `memcpy` еще надо.

Comment: Не думаю, что такой способ реально может помочь. Скорее всего в такой ситуации malloc также вернет 0 (realloc ведь ищет принципиально доступный свободный непрерывный кусок памяти с учетом того, что расширяемый кусок сейчас занимает)

Comment: `memcpy()` не надо, надо до него, чтобы не передать нулевой указатель в качестве аргумента-назначения (первый который).

Comment: @avp, там логика такая, что `realloc()` сначала выделяет новый буфер, и только после этого уничтожает старый. И если места под оба буфера недостаточно (то есть `realloc()` 1) всё равно не может переиспользовать текущий буфер и 2) возвращает `NULL`), происходит отбрасывание буфера с прошлыми данными и принудительное выделение нового. Но при нехватке места из-за фрагментации (когда освобождённый фрагмент не может объединится со смежным пустым местом) неудачей завершатся обе функции, да.

Comment: Думаю мне стоит приложить весь метод, что бы не было дискуссии не по делу.

Comment: Какая-то странная смесь C и С++.

Comment: @Arhad, прежде всего realloc смотрит, нет ли достаточно свободного места в конце расширяемого блока. Если есть, то вообще ничего не копируется (адрес начала не меняется). Если нет, то ищет нужный кусок, копирует данные и освобождает текущий. Если свободное место есть перед расширяемым куском (с учетом его уже занятого размера), то realloc возьмет его и скопирует данные к началу. ЕМНИП, как-то так

Comment: @Yami, а зачем вы умножаете на `sizeof char`? Он **всегда равен 1**. И зачем `void *`? Сделайте `rresult` сразу `char *` (и выбросьте этот ужас со `static_cast<...>`).

Comment: @avp именно, *ищет нужный кусок* и *освобождает текущий*. Если же это не удаётся сделать, вопрошающий вручную проделывает эти же две операции, но в обратном порядке (сначала освобождает текущий, а потом ищет новый). Это как бы аварийная ветка на случай, когда достаточно большого непрерывного блока нет, но есть как небольшие куски до ипосле текущего буфера, которые можно объединить при его освобождении, чтобы всё влезло.

Comment: @Yami, кстати, проверять результат `memcpy` на 0 уже поздно (она возвращает свой первый аргумент)

Comment: @avp, буду знать, хорошая информация.

Comment: @Arhad, неужели из описанного мной алгоритма не ясно, что если realloc не нашел нужный кусок (с учетом примыкающих к расширяемому свободных областей), то free с последующим malloc также завершатся неудачей?

Comment: @avp, сначала я не понял смысл словосочетания *в конце расширяемого блока*. Думал, что речь шла про блок байт текущей полезной нагрузки, а не вообще весь буфер, выделенный с запасом из кучи. Сейчас дошло.

Comment: @avp Ещё, я не знал, что `realloc()` умеет напрямую работать со структурой кучи, наживую подправляя размеры и смещения. Всегда думал, что это всего лишь тонкая обёртка над тройкой `malloc()`+`memcpy()`+`free()`.

Comment: абсолютно бессмысленная вещь... IRL если `realloc` или `malloc` вернул 0, то в си надо вывести ошибку и вызвать `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` или `abort()`, а в плюсах можно кинуть эксепшн... всё остальное — от лукавого (да, на любое правило есть исключение, но в вопросе явно не тот случай ;))...